# Assistance with comparing cells with If formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am Comparing cells in column `D` and if they match paste the value of the previous cell in column `B` into the next cell in column `B` if they do not match paste the value of the subseqent cell in column `A` into the cell in column `B`

e.g

`IF(D2=D3,B2,A2+1)"` but this is not working after running on the 1st sequence of cells in `D` I get `#Valve!"` for the rest of column `B`

I am sure this is the problem `IF(D2=D3,B2,A2+1)"` in-particular the `A2+1` reference but not sure how to call it

(Sorry if this was unclear)

Thanks

```
Sub TargetId()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("UnPivot")
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

 Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Source"
 Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = [A2].Value

With ws
lRow = ws.Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   With .Range("B3:B" & lRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(D2=D3,B2,A2+1)"
        .Value = .Value
   End With
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: it seems that your data in column `A` not numeric and `A2+1` fails. What data do you have in column A? Should it be: `IF(D2=D3,B2,A3)`?

Comment: Hello simco, I have alphanumeric

Comment: `if they do not match paste the value of the subseqent cell in column A` - as I see formula should be `.Formula = "=IF(D2=D3,B2,A3)"`. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I just tired it and that fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
With .Range("B3:B" & lRow)
    .Formula = "=IF(D2=D3,B2,A3)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```